# Heroku db:push -> Missing Sequel gem

Tags: mysql, ruby, heroku, sequel

I'm trying to push my local MySQL database to Heroku's ClearDB MySQL database.  I've gone through a lot of errors of missing gems and such, and am getting stuck on one.  I'm running:

```
heroku db:push mysql://user:password@localhost/db
```

It prompts me to enter the application name to confirm, and then I get a many errors looking like:

```
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:779:in
`report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem sequel (~> 3.20.0)
(Gem::LoadError)                                                 |
ETA:  --:--:--  from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:214:in
`activate'  from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1082:in
`gem'   from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/taps-0.3.23/bin/schema:4
```

which is weird, because I have the Sequel gem installed, and the correct version (3.20.0).  I've tried doing a complete reinstall of all my gems, and still have had no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you can use Heroku db:push for ClearDB - I simply did a local mySQL backup and then restored it directly onto the ClearDB instance - you can get the login credentials from the output of a `heroku config` in your application.

Comment: How did you restore it to the ClearDB instance?

Comment: I used mysql tools connected to the clearDB instance to do the restore (in my case I was using sequelPro for Mac to export and import the database)

Comment: I was able to use push with the tap gem, but I needed to add sqlite3 to my development group in the Gemfile. I gave heroku the fully qualified resource path `heroku db:push mysql://root:@localhost/mydb` and made sure that I had the cleardb option selected and the config val set to the same as the cleardb config setting: `heroku config:add DATABASE_URL ...`

Comment: someone might want to check the cleardb's site for first hand information. http://www.cleardb.com/developers/connect/paas/heroku/python